# What is wrong with this mat lab code?

Tags: algorithm, matlab

This is the problem:
Write a function called top_right that takes two inputs: a matrix N and a scalar non-negative integer n, in that order, where each dimension of N is greater than or equal to n. The function returns the n-by-n square array at the top right corner of N.

My code:

```
function s=top_right(A,n)
  s=A(1:n,end-n+1:end);
```

I dont know where I am wrong,
Thank you!

Comment: And what is your expected and actual output?

Comment: What is this actually about? `C++`, `opencv` or `matlab`? Remove the unrelated tags!

Comment: The function returns an nxn matrix. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Ok so things looks good here this would return an n-by-n matrix. Can you provide an example and a statement why this not work as you expect.

Answer (score 6):

Your code works fine and does what it should, but I think it is somewhere it the script you work in. To use that as a function open a new script copy

```
function s=top_right(A,n)
  s=A(1:n,end-n+1:end);
end
```

In there and save as 'top_right.m' (the name will be suggested when you save). While you work in that folder you can call your function with `top_right(A,n)`